# Model Relationships not finding the property

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a relationship between two models. My first model is the User Model, the second one is Company.

I tried adding in the User model the hasMany('App\Comapny') property, and in the Company one, belongsTo('App\User').

// In User Model

```
public function companies(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company');
}
```

// In Company Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

// And in the controller:

```
$user_id = auth()->user('id');
$user = User::find($user_id); 
return view('devices.show')->with('companies', $user->companies);
```

It should return an array with all the companies that my User has when using "$user->comapnies", however, it returns this message instead:

Property [companies] does not exist on this collection instance.

Thanks, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. I figured it out, the problem was this line:

```
$user_id = auth()->user('id');
```

It should be instead

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$user_id = auth()->user->id;
$user = User::with('companies')->where('id', $user_id)->first(); 
return view('devices.show', compact('user'));
```

Then you can access the company relation with 
$user->company[index]-> 
in the view.